# "Not realizing" vs "not having realized"?

Tags: grammar

"In a humorous gaffe, President George W. Bush once said that Ian Fleming was the discover of penicillin, not realizing that Ian Fleming was in fact the creator of James Bond."

"In a humorous gaffe, President George W. Bush once said that Ian Fleming was the discover of penicillin, not having realized that Ian Fleming was in fact James Bond's creator."

1 is correct. Is it because of the "creator" or because of the "not having realized" thing?

Comment: Hi, John, and welcome to EL&U.

Actually, I believe that both these sentences are correct.

Comment: Just because they're correct doesn't mean they're not atrocious! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I hope a linguist hops in on this one.

> ...X once **said** that... **not realizing** that ...
>
> ...X once **said** that... **not having realized** that

Both use the simple past for the first clause. This is a point in the past. Good so far.

The second clause *was occurring while* the action of the simple past took place. Therefore, *not realizing*, at that point, is correct.

> She once **drove** to Brooklyn **not realizing** that her mother no longer lived there.

The [relative past tense](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsRelativePastTense.htm) is a relative tense that refers to a time located **before** that of **a contextually determined temporal reference point**. The construction “having + verb” expresses relative past tense.

**not having realized** may usually refer to a time *completed* before the time of the first clause, the simple past.

> **Having realized** she had moved, **she drove** to the correct address.

However

> > **Not having realized** she had moved, **she drove** to the incorrect address.
>
> **not having realized** who Ian Fleming actually was, he **said** something funny (as a result).

This sounds as though the time referred to in the relative clause is still influenced by the relative clause.

I'm afraid I may not have helped you, but I believe it's acceptable.

[reference](http://www.colorado.edu/ling/courses/LAM7430/LING7430_Aspect_07/Declerck_Relative_Tense.pdf) Is there a relative past tense in English? - Renaat Declerck,  Lingua 97 (1995)